# Lerping issue with timers

Tags: c++, game-engine

I have been having an issue related to timers when I am lerping objects in my game engine. The lerping is almost correct and when I am applying the lerping to an object moving or rotating it is fine except every few seconds it appears as if the object quickly flashes to it's previous position before continuing to move smoothly.

Running the engine in windowed mode gives me 1500~fps but if I run in full screen with vsync clamping to 60fps the glitch happens a lot more often.

I have been trying to find either a good resource or explanation on lerping and how I can improve what I have.

For working out the tick gap I use:

```
float World::GetTickGap()
{
float gap = (float) (TimeMs() - m_lastTick) / m_tickDelay;
return gap > 1.f ? 1.f : gap;
}
```

My update function:

```
m_currentTick = TimeMs();
if(m_currentTick > m_lastTick+m_tickDelay)
{
    m_lastTick = m_currentTick;

            //Update actors

    }
```

Then when rendering each actor I am giving the tick gap for them to lerp between their positions.

My lerping function:

```
float math::Lerp(float a, float b, float t)
{
return a + t*(b-a);
}
```

And an example of the lerping function being called:

```
renderPosition.x = (math::Lerp(m_LastPosition.x, m_Position.x, tickDelay));
```

I'm unsure where to start on trying to fix this problem. As far as I'm aware it is the timing issues with the functions. Though could anything else cause a small dip in performance at a constant rate?

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: 1500 or 150? I don't know of many displays with a refresh rate high enough to properly display 1500 fps, much less such a rate being perceivable by the human eye.

Comment: is `tickDelay` in the last line the same as `TickGap` from the first?

Comment: The monitor itself is only capable of 60 but the engine is telling me when not under vsync it is able to draw the world 1500 times in a second. I do expect that number to drop when I start rendering more than one object.

Comment: tickDelay is the same as TickGap and that should really be changed in the engine to minimise the confusion.

Comment: Check out [Game Programming Patterns: Game Loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) it contains a thorough discussion.

Comment: At which time rendering is done? Is it in the same thread? Or it is processed after 'if(m_currentTick > m_lastTick+m_tickDelay)' ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really able to reconstruct your code from what you posted

But I remember that calling your time function more than once per frame is bad idea generally.
You seem to do that. Try thinking about what effect that has.

E.g. It might mean that the "update Actors" loops are out of sync with the "tickGap" intervals and actors are updated a second time with 0 gap.